# SQLAlchemy returns first row not correct row

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have the following query.  It always returns the first row.  I need it return the first row it finds based on the filter.  For some reason it ignores the filter and always returns ID 1 regardless of what I put in the filter.  How can I get my query to return the proper output based on the filter?

```
SUBINT_COMPLETE_LIST = ['id',
                        'carrier_vlan',
                        'cust_vlan_ipsec',
                        'cust_vlan_wan',
                        'hub_wan1_public_ip',
                        'ip_transit',
                        'neighbor_ip',
                        'user_account',
                        'customer',
                        'created_at',
                        'status',
                        'location',
                        'is_primary'
                        ]

#creates list from SubInterfaces models
customer_fields =[getattr(SubInterfaces, ls) for ls in SUBINT_COMPLETE_LIST]

customer = "Joe"

print(f"{db.session.query(*customer_fields).filter(customer == customer).first()}")
```

Comment: you filter on `customer == customer` so `joe == joe` which is always true. And thats why your query just returns the first column from the table

Comment: customer is the name of the column.

Comment: ok but i don't think that python knows that because normally there is a Model behind and the filter looks like `filter(MyModel.column == valueVariable)`